# Delete From Where Exists -- Throwing Error

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

The query below will select and display all dupes in one of my tables.

```
SELECT KeyReport, Analytics, Description, AsOfDate, COUNT(*) as CNT
FROM  `corp-analytics.Reports.Metrics`
GROUP BY KeyReport, Analytics, Description, AsOfDate
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 AND AsOfDate IN('01-03-2019','01-17-2019')
```

So, if I use that as a sub-query in the query below....

```
Delete
From Table 
Where Exists (sub-query)
```

I would expect it to delete all dupes, but instead, I get this message:

```
Cannot set destination table in jobs with DML statements
```

So, my question is, why doesn't the query below delete dupes?

```
Delete
From `corp-analytics.Reports.Metrics`
Where Exists (SELECT KeyReport, Analytics, Description, AsOfDate, COUNT(*) as CNT
FROM  `corp-analytics.Reports.Metrics`
GROUP BY KeyReport, Analytics, Description, AsOfDate
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 AND AsOfDate IN('01-03-2019','01-17-2019'))
```

I don't have any unique IDs in this table.

Comment: You can't set a destination table with a DELETE query, like the error message says.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this?
Your HAVING clause is filtering on a count(*). You won't find duplicates after you've already done the grouping.

```
Delete
From `corp-analytics.Reports.Metrics`
Where Exists (SELECT KeyReport, Analytics, Description, AsOfDate, COUNT(*) as CNT
FROM  `corp-analytics.Reports.Metrics`
GROUP BY KeyReport, Analytics, Description, AsOfDate
HAVING CNT > 1 AND AsOfDate IN('01-03-2019','01-17-2019'))
```